# Odd A tag behavior, on mousedown the cursor changes to 'not-allowed'

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I've got a simple A tag:

```
<a href="#/URL" id="someID">Link Text</a>
```

Every now and again IE gets confused the the link stops working. When the mouse hovering over the link, its a normal cursor, on mouse-down it changes to 'not-allowed' and on mouse-up nothing happens.

I can refresh the page and it works normal again for awhile, then it just stops working again.

How can I determine what is happening and fix it? There is no console output, there is script or events on the A tag or any of its parents. IE just borks.

This is an Angular application if it matters at all.

For clarification, I don't want any pointer changes at all, I don't want the link to randomly stop working. I just want the A tag to behave as normal. It does so in all browsers except IE.

Comment: If you want a pointer when you hover over the link you can just do in css      #someID{cursor:pointer};  If thats what is concerning you...

Comment: Inspect the live html when it does that. Sounds like perhaps there is some invalid html being generated